# Is there any way to find the database error codes for Bookshelf.js ? Iam using postgreSQL + ember.js + bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ember.js

How to know the error codes for Bookshelf.js? so that i can handle any type of error ? Iam using ember.js too in my project (node.js+ember.js+bookshelf.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bookshelf and the postgres driver will mostly just surface the errors generated within postgresql itself, which you can find [listed here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/errcodes-appendix.html) (for PostgreSQL 9.6).

To address your comment, the mechanism you use to detect any errors is the same. Bookshelf exposes a promise interface where `.catch((error) => {})` is the API you use to catch all errors. There is also a callback-style variant of this available using `.asCallback((error, result) => {})`. That's the mechanism you use to detect errors.

As to "handling" them. You can only "handle" as in do any meaningful recovery from a very small set of errors, and usually only if you know to expect them in advance. Typically, the only meaningful thing you can do with an error is just log it. You're code can't do anything to handle invalid database credentials, network connectivity errors, the database server's disk being full, etc. You don't need to know or add to your code a comprehensive list of every low level error code each database server might throw. There is no purpose to that exercise. Just log your error and do what you can to cleanly abort the request/process that encountered it.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Lyons for your kind reply , I also want to know how we can handle errors for any kind of  database in bookshelf.js. How an ORM like bookshelf handles these errors. As the error codes will be vendor specific  for different databases.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Lyons , really your answer helped me alot.